# (Historical perspective) CSP and SAT inter-fertilization

Tags: backtracking, constraint-programming, satisfiability, constraint-satisfaction

[Disclaimer: this is a rather specialized question]

It is known that techniques like Conflict-Driven Clause Learning (CDCL) and back-jumping -- which improved the Satisfiability (SAT) strategies exponentially -- were actually inspired [2] by Constraint Satisfaction Problem (CSP) techniques (so-called nogoods [1], or generalized nogoods).

But while SAT evolved and improved with these techniques, CSP doesn't seem to widely benefit from these ideas.

My question : why aren't these ideas ubiquitous in CSP like they are in SAT ? What happened ? What makes them unsuitable ? Is it "just" a question of domain size ?

Secondary question: are there any other ideas that jumped the divide between the two ? Instances of the CSP community inspiring the SAT community and/or vice versa ?

[1]: Generalized NoGoods in CSPs, G. Katsirelos, F. Bacchus

[2]: Using CSP Look-Back Techniques to Solve Real-World SAT Instances, R. Bayardo, R. Schrag